# In registered model display list of all User(Foreign key)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

[In image you can see i have only few user that i added from add button but i want to display all user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHX3m.png)

```
class Notification_user (models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assign_jobs_notification = models.ManyToManyField(AppJob)
```

In admin section when i register joblist then it shows only user that are add by add Job List. But i want to display all users.

here is my admin.py

```
class NotificationAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    assign_jobs_notification = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
      queryset=AppJob.objects.all(), 
      required=False,
      widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
        verbose_name=_('Jobs_Notifications'),
        is_stacked=False
      )

    )

    class Meta:
      model = User
      exclude =[]


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(NotificationAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

      if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['assign_jobs_notification'].initial = self.instance.assign_jobs_notification.all()

    def save(self, commit=True):
      appjob = super(NotificationAdminForm, self).save(commit=False)

      if commit:
        appjob.save()

      if appjob.pk:
        appjob.assign_jobs_notification = self.cleaned_data['assign_jobs_notification']
        self.save_m2m()

      return appjob

class NotificationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = NotificationAdminForm
admin.site.register(Notification_user,NotificationAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the default behaviour of a `OneToOneField`. As the name implies and as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) says, this is for a 1:1 relationship. You can see an example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) which basically says a restaurant (physically) can be at one address. In your case, that means that a user will be assigned to a job listing instance. What I think you should use is a `ForeignKey` for that.

```py
class JobList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Comment: I'm glad that helped. If it helped you and it worked, it'd be much appreciated if you mark the question as correct, thanks.

Comment: sorry but that not helped in solving my problem.

Comment: Please share the issues you’re having on your question do we can see and help you

Comment: Do you have more users for that JobList instance? Please share your `admin.py` code as well

Comment: I updated my question with image and admin.py Please check the issue again.